# Is there a Vim syntax file for ANSI-colored output of CLI apps?

Tags: vim, colors, syntax-highlighting

I have quite a lot of Perl scripts which print colored output to the terminal, using `Term::ANSIColor`. This is the same as when a shell script does e.g.

```
echo -e '\e[1;31mError:\e[0m Your fault.'
```

Viewing log files of these commands works in `less` (with the `-R` switch), but in Vim, the color characters are displayed raw like this:

```
^[[1;31mError:^[[0m Your fault.
```

I would do a syntax file to match these markers, conceal them, and color the resulting syntax regions accordingly, but first I wanted to check whether there is something like this already.

Comment: ... And it's very difficult to Google for that topic. Every query that includes "vim" and "colors" brings up hundreds of color schemes, which is not what I want.

Comment: `vim ansi color` is quite helpful, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look into this plugin, it's likely what you want:

[AnsiEsc.vim : ansi escape sequences concealed, but highlighted as specified](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302)